# Reorder columns in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following HTML structure for a form (simplified):

```
<form class="form">
  <div class="formRow">
    <div class="formCol" data-id="First">First</div>
    <div class="formCol" data-id="Last">Last</div>
    <div class="formCol" data-id="Whatever">Whatever</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="formRow">
    <div class="formCol" data-id="City">City</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="formRow">
    <div class="formCol" data-id="Country">Country</div>
    <div class="formCol" data-id="Phone">Phone</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

As I don't have any control over the output, I need to reorder the columns by using JavaScript:

```
const form = (() => {
  const colClassName = 'formCol';
  const rowClassName = 'formRow';
  const clearClassName = 'clear';

  function createRow(elForm) {
    const elRow = document.createElement('div');
    const elClear = document.createElement('div');
    elRow.className = rowClassName;
    elClear.className = clearClassName;
    elRow.appendChild(elClear);
    elForm.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', elRow);

    return elRow;
  }

  function moveColumn(elForm, elRow, colName) {
    const elCol = elForm.querySelector(`.${colClassName}[data-id='${colName}']`);
    elRow.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', elCol);
  }

  function removeEl(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }

  function reorder(elForm, order) {
    const elRows = elForm.querySelectorAll(`.${rowClassName}`);
    const maxRows = Math.max(elRows.length, order.length);
    let elCol;

    for (var i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
      if (order[i]) {
        if (!elRows[i]) {
          elRows[i] = createRow(elForm);
        }

        if (!Array.isArray(order[i])) {
          moveColumn(elForm, elRows[i], order[i]);
        } else {
          for (j = order[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            moveColumn(elForm, elRows[i], order[i][j]);
          };
        }
      } else {
        elCol = elRows[i].querySelector(`.${colClassName}`);

        if (!elCol) {
          removeEl(elRows[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    reorder,
    // other functions for form
  };
})();

form.reorder(document.querySelector('.form'), [
  ['Last', 'City'],
  'First',
  'Country',
  'Phone',
]);
```

It does the following:

- Reorders the elements as specified in the array (multiple columns).
- Does not delete columns if they are not in the array (see column "Whatever").
- Creates new rows if necessary and deletes empty rows

While that works as is (see https://jsfiddle.net/6cy4mjvd/), I don't know if there are ways to improve readability / code in general, e.g. it feels wrong how I currently create new rows and modify `elRows` and also that I  pass `elForm` to all helper functions... and probably a few other spots.

Btw. I plan on adding other functions other than `reorder` to modify the form. That's why I return an object (line `// other functions for form`) in the function.

Comment: I don't understand why 'Last' and 'City' are inside an array so I would simply inject CSS style that sets form's `display` to `flex` and column's `order` to a value derived from the element's index in the array.

Comment: @wOxxOm In this case, 'Last' and 'City' are in an array because they should be displayed in two columns. Using `display: flex` on the form would allow me to reorder the rows, but I also (sometimes) want to move the columns to a completely different row. That's why I only used `display: flex` on the rows (see jsfiddle). Using JavaScript is also sightly easier to use (IMO) than having to hard code the order in CSS, e.g. I can display the form in 3 columns with `reorder(el, ['Phone', 'Country', 'City'], ['First', 'Last', 'Whatever'])`.

Comment: Based on how the reorder function is called, I expected to see `Phone` in the fourth row. In the fiddle, it is left in the third row. Am I misunderstanding something or is this a bug?

Comment: @Gerrit0 "Phone" should be in the fourth column and actually is for me in Chrome/Safari at least. I should probably check FF... May I ask what browser you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@demrks please take a look at the code below. It's a result of multiple refactoring iterations.

While the original code does the job, I find it very hard to read. Hopefully, you agree that the improved version reads better, even though there's very little new in it. Many developers including myself believe that *readability* is a super important aspect of coding because it directly affects *complexity*, and thus *correctness* of the code.

Here's the list of techniques I applied (in order of importance as I understand things):

---

**Naming**

Name things properly and do not abbreviate words. `createNewRowElementAndInsertIntoForm(...)` is definitely not a short name, but it's describing what it does with 100% precision.

Similarly, original `elCol` transformed into `columnElement`. It may be funny, but first seeing `elCol` I thought I'm reading code in Spanish. :)

Please never never never use the `i`, `j`, `c`, and similar. They are absolutely meaningless. Yes, the other dev "may understand" it, but you don't want anyone to *guess* what the code does. Spell things out, in most of the modern editors it's a matter of hitting `<F2>`.

**Temporary <strike>variables</strike> constants**

Do not hesitate to introduce reusable temporary constants with descriptive names. They make cryptic conditions `if (order[i])` or `if (!elRows[i])` relay the intent of the writer.

**Avoid branching when possible, or minimize its "scope"**

An unnecessary if-then-else for processing array/non-array orders may be generalized, if we normalize the array first.

*Was*:

```
if (!Array.isArray(order[i])) {
  moveColumn(elForm, elRows[i], order[i]);
} else {
  for (j = order[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    moveColumn(elForm, elRows[i], order[i][j]);
  };
}
```

*Became* (longer because of the name, but the branching is almost eliminated by a ternary operator that cleans the input):

```
const normalizerRowPrescribedOrder =
  Array.isArray(rowPrescribedOrder) ? rowPrescribedOrder : [rowPrescribedOrder];

for (let columnIndex = normalizerRowPrescribedOrder.length - 1; columnIndex >= 0; columnIndex--) {
  findColumnByNameAndMoveToBeginningOfRow(formElement, currentRowElement, normalizerRowPrescribedOrder[columnIndex]);
};
```

**"Newspaper"**

Make code read top to bottom aka *newspaper style* (`reorder()` is the entry point which invokes `createNewRowElementAndInsertIntoForm()`, therefore `reorder()` should go first). Forcing the reader to jump around the code is distracting from the act of active reading, therefore leading to avoidable complications.

---

## Result

```
const form = (() => {
  const columnClassName = 'formCol';
  const rowClassName = 'formRow';
  const clearClassName = 'clear';

  function reorderForm(formElement, prescribedOrder) {
    const rowElementList = formElement.querySelectorAll(`.${rowClassName}`);
    const maxRowLength = Math.max(rowElementList.length, prescribedOrder.length);

    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < maxRowLength; rowIndex++) {
      const currentRowElement = rowElementList[rowIndex] || createNewRowElementAndInsertIntoForm(formElement);

      const rowPrescribedOrder = prescribedOrder[rowIndex];
      if (!rowPrescribedOrder) {
        const columnElement = currentRowElement.querySelector(`.${columnClassName}`);
        if (!columnElement) {
          removeRowElement(currentRowElement);
        }
      } else {
        const normalizedRowPrescribedOrder = Array.isArray(rowPrescribedOrder) ? rowPrescribedOrder : [rowPrescribedOrder];
        for (let columnIndex = normalizedRowPrescribedOrder.length - 1; columnIndex >= 0; columnIndex--) {
          findColumnByNameAndMoveToBeginningOfRow(formElement, currentRowElement, normalizedRowPrescribedOrder[columnIndex]);
        };
      }
    }
  }

  function createNewRowElementAndInsertIntoForm(formElement) {
    const rowElement = document.createElement('div');
    rowElement.className = rowClassName;

    const clearElement = document.createElement('div');
    clearElement.className = clearClassName;

    rowElement.appendChild(clearElement);

    formElement.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', rowElement);

    return rowElement;
  }

  function findColumnByNameAndMoveToBeginningOfRow(formElement, rowElement, columnName) {
    const columnElement = formElement.querySelector(`.${columnClassName}[data-id='${columnName}']`);
    rowElement.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', columnElement);
  }

  function removeRowElement(rowElement) {
    rowElement.parentNode.removeChild(rowElement);
  }

  return {
    reorderForm,
    // other functions for form
  };
})();

form.reorderForm(document.querySelector('.form'), [
  ['Last', 'City'],
  'First',
  'Country',
  'Phone',
]);
```

## P.S.

It's really nice to see how one uses native API instead of jQuery!

Comment: Thanks, the names make it indeed easier to read (although they look a little log at first). I only used jQuery a few years back because it made it easier to work with old IE versions :)